# Discord bot - have bot initiate conversation

Tags: discord

I am starting with a new Discord bot using `discord.js`.

I wanted to add an onboarding process, but saw that the questions can only be used for role and channel assignments. So instead I want the bot to ask the onboarding questions after the user joins.

But is it possible for the bot to be the one that initiates a conversation with a user? instead of the user sending a message?